# pushd with rd doesn't work as I want

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I've tried like this

```
pushd \\somedrive.se\Install\Paket\XXX\
echo "start..."
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /b bu* ') do echo /q %i
popd
```

and got this output when running from a script:

```
Z:\Paket\XXX>echo "start..."
"start..."
/b was unexpected at this time.
Z:\Paket\XXX>for /f d /b bu* ') do echo /q i
```

But if I do it directly in the command window it works?

```
Z:\Paket\XXX>for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /b bu* ') do echo /q %i
Z:\Paket\XXXX>echo /q bu.1_2.zip
/q bu.1_2.zip
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not related to `pushd`.
You need to use double percent signs when run from batch (as oposed to directly from cmd line.), so it should become:
`for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b bu* ') do echo /q %%i`

MS reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx